# Правильный ли формат JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

```
{'id_user':'1', 'time':'123456340', 'message':'Da, privet'} 
{'id_user':'145', 'time':'123456123', 'message':'Privet'}
```

эти строки возвращаются от

```
each(result, value){
}
```

внутри цикла хочу получить значение *value.time* - но пишет underfined

Comment: Полную функцию можно? А так смотрите, что говорит `console.log()`

Comment: console.log(value) дает результат: {"id_user":"145", "time":"123456123", "message":"Privet"} но console.log(value.time) дает underfined

Comment: А  

    typeof value

?

Comment: $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/chat/GetDialog',
          data:  {idUser : idUser},
          success: function(data){
                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }); 
          }
        });

Comment: ответ: 0: "{'id_user':'1', 'time':'123456340', 'message':'Da, privet'}"
1: "{'id_user':'145', 'time':'123456123', 'message':'Privet'}"
2: "{"id_user":"145", "time":"123456123", "message":"Privet"}"

Comment: typeof value выдает string.

Answer (score 3):

.

```
JSON.parse( value ).time
```

Comment: сторона php: echo json_encode($messages); die(); в $messages у меня строка по формату json

Comment: @IOleg вы поняли, почему так? Я думаю немаловажно разъяснить, почему данные еще нужно было через функцию parse() прогнать.

Comment: разъясните - не помешает. как  понял, чтобы распарсить строку которая из себя представляет запись json и чтобы получить доступ к элемента json

Comment: @IOleg верно! Но в методе `$.ajax()` есть хак! Вам нужно добавить свойство: `dataType: 'json'` и данные в функцию будут приходить как `json` объект.